# With Zend, execute an instruction when onclick on a button

Tags: php, zend-framework, onclick, global-variables

I'm new to Zend and I have some questions:
I will try to simplify the exemple.
I have created a global vaiable in the bootstrap and set it to false

```
    Zend_Registry::set('var1', FALSE);
```

and I have created a file Translate.php:

```
<?php

class CMS_Application_Resource_Translate extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract {

public function my_function() {
    //do Something
    }
```

}

And in every controller I put this code:

```
 public function init()
{
if (Zend_Registry::get('var1')) {
   $instance1=new CMS_Application_Resource_Translate();
   $instance1->my_function();
}
}
```

And I have created a button that figured in all the site pages, when I click on this button, I want to set the global variable to true, so that the init() function of the controllers work.
But I have a problem:
How can I execute a function that changes the global variable to true on click on the button?

Comment: PHP is server side, it has no concept of button clicks.  You'll either have to submit a form or do an AJAX request.

Comment: @GordonM Should I get/set the global variable with an ajax request? I can not do it otherwise?

Comment: can I pass the variable through the url localhost/controller/action/var1=true??

Comment: @Bouaziz ,of course you can just append ?var1=true after the .../action and simply query the request object in the bootstrap to set the property